# Matlab: PDF from a Markov Chain

Tags: matlab, markov-chains

I have generated the Markov Chain using Matlab. From the generated Markov Chain, I need to calculate the probability density function (PDF).

- How should i do it?
  Should I use the generated Markov Chain directly in any of the PDF functions?
  or
  Should I do any pre-processing of the data before finding the PDF?

The Markov Chain is generated using the following code:

```
%  x     = the quantity corresponding to each state, typical element x(i)
%  P     = Markov transition matrix, typical element p(i,j) i,j=1,...n
%  pi0   = probability distribution over initial state
%  T     = number of periods to simulate 
%  chain = sequence of realizations from the simulation

n = length(x); % what is the size of the state vector?
E = rand(1,T); % T-vector of draws from independent uniform [0,1]  

cumsumP = P*triu(ones(size(P)));
E0   = rand(1,1);
ppi0 = [0,cumsum(pi0)];
s0   = ((E0<=ppi0(2:n+1)).*(E0>ppi0(1:n)))';
s    = s0; 

for t=1:T,
state(:,t) = s;
ppi        = [0,s'*cumsumP];
s          = ((E(t)<=ppi(2:n+1)).*(E(t)>ppi(1:n)))';
end

chain = x'*state;
```

After generating the Markov Chain, I need to calculate the probability density.

- How can I find the probability density using Matlab?

Comment: Have you had a look at Matlab's [``pdf``](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdf.html)-function? It is part of the [statistics toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/) though.

Comment: @Schorsch ya, i have used the pdf function 'ksdensity' as follows,     [f,xi] = ksdensity(chain,bins,'function','PDF');             Is it correct?

Comment: Without being more specific on what you encountered, it is difficult to say if your use of ``kdensity`` is *correct*. It sure looks like the [example on mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the states as single values in vector `chain`, you can simply make a histogram and normalize it.

```
chainPdf = hist(chain) / length(chain);
```

You may need to specify the number of bins or bin centers when calling [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html).